# Convert leaflet map snippet to image

Tags: pdf-generation, leaflet, html-to-pdf

I need to export a page that contain leaflet map to pdf. I tried to convert the map container to image but thats not working perfectly.
The code I used is here 
http://jsfiddle.net/Sq7hg/2/

```
html2canvas([document.getElementById('mydiv')], {
onrendered: function (canvas) {
    document.getElementById('canvas').appendChild(canvas);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(data)
    // AJAX call to send `data` to a PHP file that creates an image from the dataURI string and saves it to a directory on the server

    var image = new Image();
    image.src = data;
    document.getElementById('image').appendChild(image);
}
```

});

This code not working perfectly for leaflet map.How can I implement this ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you'd better off using [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) plugin, which does exactly that. There is a demo linked from the header. The main catch is forcing Leaflet to use canvas for rendering.

Comment: Thanks llja..I tried this.But its working only when there are no markers.when ever a marker is added to map, this error is shon in console 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined'

Comment: great..it worked.. :) marker size wasn't defined before and that was the reason for the error..Now its perfect..Thanks llja..

Comment: Does this plugin has any dependencies like d3-queue?

Comment: It has dependencies (see `package.json`), but there is a pre-built minified version in the repository (see the docs) that you can use.

Answer (score 6):

I had a problem to export the leaflet map with special markers, I tried to use the plugin [leaflet-image](https://github.com/mapbox/leaflet-image) but it works only with standard markers.

**At the end I created the map in the server (Node).**

I wrote a post, How to export the leaflet map to pdf, see link below

[Export leaflet map to pdf report](https://orenw.wordpress.com/2015/06/07/export-leaflet-map-to-image/)